# Xcode Resizing UIWebView to content after back button

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I am building an app which gets its HTML contents from a web feed (JSON). The length of the pages vary from a single line to hundreds of lines. 
Although the UIWebView is perfectly capable of scrolling, I need a UITableView under the UIWebView to display additional menu items. This means that I need the whole view to scroll and not just the UIWebView. This also means that the UIWebView shouldn't scroll at all and that it should scale to the content.

[image: In short, my view is like this:]

The UIImageView is the header, the UIWebView is the content, the UITableView is the footer menu. The hidden button is there to create the segue to itself.

I resize the UIWebView with this code:

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
     WebView.frame = CGRectMake(WebView.frame.origin.x, WebView.frame.origin.y, WebView.frame.width, [WebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero].height);
}
```

That works for the UIWebView and it gets correctly resized. The UITableView however is shown over resized UIWebView, it does not get pushed down by the bigger UIWebView at all.

Secondly, this view has a Segue to itself (its like a wiki structure with internal references), which works like a charm. But when I go back a page the UIWebView stays its original size again, it doesn't get resized. The segue makes the app forget the new size of the UIWebView somehow.

As you can see I'm struggling with this, everything seems so static and absolute while i need some 'relative positioning'. But then again I'm new to iOS programming and thinking like a webdeveloper. Why doesn't the segue remember the UIWebView height? Why Isnt the UITableView pushed down? What am I missing here? (I must be missing something big right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To adjust `TableView` as per `Webview` ,set your `TableView` `frame` using `height` of `webview` inside the `webViewDidFinishLoad` itself,

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
     WebView.frame = CGRectMake(WebView.frame.origin.x, WebView.frame.origin.y, WebView.frame.width, [WebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero].height);
     TableView.frame = CGRectMake(TableView.frame.origin.x,WebView.frame.size.height + 20.0,TableView.frame.size.width,TableView.frame.size.height); // like this
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Although iphonics answer is basically the same, yours is much clearer.
It solves the pushing down issue.


What it does not solve is the issue that the segue does not remember the new height of the UIWebView. So it just popped back when I change views or even scrolled.


The solution to that I found in another SO thread (13855810).


I needed to disable 'Use Autolayout' to stop the layouts from automatically adjusting (sounds obvious now). You can find the 'Use Autolayout' option in the 'File inspector', or the the first button/tab in the settings bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can position you controls after one another like below

```
CGRect rect=imageView.frame;
float y=rect.origin.y;

//We need to just change the y from the next control so for the next control y would be.

y=y+rect.size.height+20.0;// 20.0 px padding

//Now use the above rect to set the frame for next control in your case its webview

rect=webView.frame;

rect.origin.y=y;

webView.frame=rect; //Re-Assign with changed y value

//Now move to next

y=y+rect.size.height+20.0;// 20.0 px padding

rect=tblView.frame;

rect.origin.y=y;

tblView.frame=rect; //Re-Assign with changed y value
```

Your all the controls should be aligned vertically one after another, you can put this code in a method, and call the method, whenever you feel the frame is changing for any control..

Hope this helps..